# Place to host picture/sound gallery

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

I have the following problem.

I own a wallpaper/ringtone collection mobile app and I need a place to host the collection itself.

So I need a hosting with following parameters:

- 1-2 GB disk space
- large/unlimited traffic (it will be media-file traffic)
- large/unlimited uniq users

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at bluehost? https://www.bluehost.com/cgi/info/hosting_features